# skemitternode collision with skspritenode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have the following two functions in swift for collision detection between an SKEmitterNode and an SKSpriteNode however I keep getting a dynamicCastFailed exception whenever my particle emitter and the sprite collide:

```
func projectileDidCollideWithMonster(projectile:SKEmitterNode, monster:SKSpriteNode) {
        println("Hit")
        projectile.removeFromParent()
        monster.removeFromParent()
    }

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    // 1
    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    // 2
    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Monster != 0) &&
        (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Projectile != 0)) {
            projectileDidCollideWithMonster(firstBody.node as SKEmitterNode, monster: secondBody.node as SKSpriteNode)
    }

}
```

Is it possible to make `SKEmitterNodes` collide with `SKSpriteNodes` or will this not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your bodies switched. I believe it should be this:

```
projectileDidCollideWithMonster(secondBody.node as SKEmitterNode, monster: firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode)
```